# How to specify basehref in Django

Tags: django

Is it possible to launch Django app with `BASEPATH=/api` or just `BASEPATH=/` based on any configuration?

Comment: You can access any environmental variable in python using `os.environ('ENV_NAME', DEFAULT)`. Just remember to `import os`.

Comment: Can try prepending /api to all url patterns in project's urls.py file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @narenda-choudhary comment

In file `settings.py`, where `BASEPATH` is env variable with relative path

```
BASEHREF = os.environ.get('BASEPATH', '/')
```

Then in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^{}'.format(settings.BASEHREF), include([
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ])),
]
```